# "Shared secret" for JWT Authentication SOA

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, soa

I have several services and I'm using OAuth2 with Authorization server which returns JWT token. I'm going to use the same JWT token for authorization for all my services(please let me know if it's a good approach). Also if I follow that approach I'll need to share my secret(signature) between all my services. Please let me know if it's a good approach(I think that there should be some common storage for secrets and in case of the update it should update secrets on all services but I'm not sure if there is an existing solution for that and where this solution is ok or not).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better security it is recommended to use *private*/*public* key approach instead of shared key.

[*JWKS*](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks) is a standard for such implementation. The idea is that you keep *private* and *public* keys on your [*OAuth2*](https://oauth.net/2/) server and have your service call back to OAuth2 to get the *public key* in order to validate JWT token. For performance reasons you can cache that public key in order not to call OAuth2 server on every validation.

If you are using Spring you can also use  [`org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkTokenStore`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk/JwkTokenStore.html) that does both validation and caching for you.

You can alternatively do the same with shared key but this will require HTTPS connection back to OAuth2 server in order not to expose it on network.